# Dijsktra method not working

Tags: java, eclipse

So trying to make dijsktra algorithm work and apparently im removing the wrong node according to labb assistant (who is no longer available for help)
These are his comments:

> "the loop that you are using in the Dijkstra method (lines 158 - 178). For it to be correct, you need to loop through the outer arcs of your minNode (in your case, "n"), and then pick up the node with the minimum cost as your minNode. In your case, you always remove the first node from the tempNode list instead of the minNode. Please resubmit the modified Network.java file."

and these are lines 157-181:

```
while (! tempNodes.isEmpty()) { // repeat until all nodes become permanent
        Node n = tempNodes.get(0);
        double min= Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

            if(n.value < min){
                min = n.value;
            }


        for(Arc a: n.arcList){
            if(n.value + a.weight < a.head.value){
                a.head.value = n.value + a.weight;  // Update the weight of each node that is adjacent to the minimum-
                n.prev = a;
            }

        tempNodes.remove(n);}//Remove the minimum-weight node n from tempNodes    
    }

    Node k;// Represent a tree by assigning 1 to its arcs and 0 to all other arcs.
    for (String nodeName: nodeMap.keySet()) {
         k = nodeMap.get(nodeName);
         if(k.prev != null) {
              k.prev.alvalue = 1.0;
        }
    }
```

am i correct in assuming the only issue is that im removing n instead of min mayby?

Il just add the rest of the lines:

```
public class Network {
// Attributes
public String name;
public HashMap<String, Node> nodeMap;

// Constructor
public Network(String name, String inputFileName) {
// Initialize the attributes
this.name = name;
this.nodeMap = new HashMap<String, Node>();

// You MAY need these local variables to store values or objects
// temporarily while constructing a new Network object
String line, arcID, tailName, headName;
Node tail, head;
double weight;
Arc forwardArc, backwardArc;

try {
// Get access to the contents of an ASCII file
File file = new File(inputFileName);
FileReader fReader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);

// Read the first line, and do nothing to skip it
line = bReader.readLine();
// Read the second line, which represents the first
// (undirected) arc stored in the file
line = bReader.readLine();
// Store each element of the network in forward star.
while (line != null) {
// Split each line into an array of 4 Strings
// using ; as separator.
String[] tokens = line.split(";");
arcID = tokens[0];
tailName = tokens[1];
headName = tokens[2];
weight = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);


// Check if nodeMap contains a Node whose name is tailName or headName.
if(nodeMap.containsKey(tailName)){
    tail = nodeMap.get(tailName);
}
else{
    tail = new Node(tailName, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, new LinkedList());
    nodeMap.put(tailName, tail);
}

if(nodeMap.containsKey(headName)){
    head = nodeMap.get(headName);
}
else{
    head = new Node(headName, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, new LinkedList());
    nodeMap.put(headName, tail);
}
// If not, create it, assign it to tail or head, and add it to nodeMap.
// Otherwise, retrieve it from nodeMap.

// Then, create two Arcs:
// one from tail to head, to be added to outArc of tail
// one from head to tail, to be added to outArc of head.
forwardArc = new Arc(arcID+"a",tail,head,weight);
backwardArc = new Arc(arcID+"b",head,tail,weight);
tail.arcList.add(forwardArc);
head.arcList.add(backwardArc);

// Read the next line
line = bReader.readLine(); }
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}


// Save
public void save(String outputFileName) {
    // This object represents an output file, out.txt, located at ./data/.
                File file = new File(outputFileName);
                // This object represents ASCII data (to be) stored in the file
                FileWriter fWriter;
                try {
                    //writing to the output-file
                    fWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                    fWriter.write("TLID "+"\t");
                    fWriter.write("NAME "+"\t");
                    fWriter.write("ALVALUE"+"\n");

                    for (Map.Entry<String, Node> entry : nodeMap.entrySet()) {
                        String key = entry.getKey();
                        Object value = entry.getValue();
                        Node values = (Node) value;
                      for (Arc A: values.arcList) {
                          String TLID = A.name.substring(0,A.name.length()-1);

                            fWriter.write(TLID+"\t");
                            fWriter.write(A.name+"\t");
                            fWriter.write(A.alvalue+"\n");
                        }
                    }


                    fWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}

public void printNodes(){
System.out.println("\tNODE NAME\tWEIGHT");
Node node;
for (String nodeName: nodeMap.keySet()) { // loop thru nodeMap
node = nodeMap.get(nodeName);
System.out.print("\t" + node.name); // \t represents tab space
System.out.print("\t\t" + node.value);
System.out.println();
}
```

}

```
public void printArcs(){
    System.out.print("TLID "+"\t");
    System.out.print("NAME "+"\t");
    System.out.print("ALVALUE "+"\n");

    for (Map.Entry<String, Node> entry : nodeMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        Node values = (Node) value;
      for (Arc A: values.arcList) {
          String TLID = A.name.substring(0,A.name.length()-1);
          System.out.print(TLID+"\t");
          System.out.print(A.name+"\t");
          System.out.print(A.alvalue+"\n");

        }
    }
}
public void dijkstra(Node origin) {

    // Set the value (representing shortest path distance) of origin to 0
     origin.value = 0;

    // Create a set of nodes, called tempNodes, whose shortest path distances are not permanently determined. Initially, this set contains all nodes.
     List<Node> tempNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    for (String nodeName: nodeMap.keySet()) {
     tempNodes.add(nodeMap.get(nodeName));
     }

    // Perform Dijkstra
    while (! tempNodes.isEmpty()) { // repeat until all nodes become permanent
        Node n = tempNodes.get(0);
        double min= Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

            if(n.value < min){
                min = n.value;
            }


        for(Arc a: n.arcList){
            if(n.value + a.weight < a.head.value){
                a.head.value = n.value + a.weight;  // Update the weight of each node that is adjacent to the minimum-
                n.prev = a;
            }

        tempNodes.remove(n);}//Remove the minimum-weight node n from tempNodes    
    }

    Node k;// Represent a tree by assigning 1 to its arcs and 0 to all other arcs.
    for (String nodeName: nodeMap.keySet()) {
         k = nodeMap.get(nodeName);
         if(k.prev != null) {
              k.prev.alvalue = 1.0;
        }
    }
```

}

```
private void clearArcWeight() {
     Node n;
    for (String nodeName: nodeMap.keySet()) {
     n = nodeMap.get(nodeName);
     for(Arc a: n.arcList){
     a.weight = 0.0;
     }
     }
    }

public void dijkstra(Node origin, Node destination) {
 dijkstra(origin); // or this.dijkstra(origin);
 clearArcWeight();
 trace(destination);
}

// Represent a tree by assigning 1 to its arcs and 0 to all other arcs.

private void trace(Node n){
    Arc a = n.prev;
    while (a != null) {
     a.weight = 1.0;
     a = a.tail.prev;
     }
}

public HashMap<String, Node> getNodeMap(){
    return nodeMap;
}

public void dijkstraByName(String string) {

    dijkstra(nodeMap.get(string));
}
```

}

Comment: What data structure you use for `tempNodes`?

Comment: where are lines 157-181 in the code??

Comment: those are lines 157-181

Comment: List<Node> tempNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

Comment: You are using a `List`? Is this Dijkstra shortest path algorithm? It doesn't seem so.

Comment: ok i cant comment with that many chars...

Comment: if(nodeMap.containsKey(tailName)){
  tail = nodeMap.get(tailName);
 }
 else{
  tail = new Node(tailName, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, new LinkedList());
  nodeMap.put(tailName, tail);
 }
  
 if(nodeMap.containsKey(headName)){
  head = nodeMap.get(headName);
 }
 else{
  head = new Node(headName, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, new LinkedList());
  nodeMap.put(headName, tail);
 }

Answer (score 1):

I might be able to give a little hint here... If you look at these lines:

```
Node n = tempNodes.get(0);
// [...n is not changed here...]
tempNodes.remove(n);
```

you will realize that the n passed into remove() will never be anything else than the result of 'tempNodes.get(0)'. That's why the first Node is always removed from the list.

Comment: Yes as far as i understand n is the wrong one to remove altogether. or do i need to change my loops so that n is the right one?

Comment: It's likely to be the wrong one. Yes, you'll need to fix that loop just a little, I think.

Comment: so according to the comments i received from the instructor i need to remove the min value from my templist. But is that my min or am i just way off. as in "min = n.value"

Comment: It's your first Node in your List, that's all you know, so very likely it's not the min node...not sure how much help I should give you here :). Perhaps if you think about how you would select (only) the smallest thing from a bunch of things in real life?

Comment: Y by comparing it to the others and choosing the smallest one sure. and dont worry there is plagiarism checks and shit when i turn it in. You will not be helping me cheat or anything of the sort

Comment: Maybe I am a sadist? Not really... Ok, further hint: you need to remember which node was the 'most minimum' node so far in each turn of the loop.

Comment: so the misstake is in for(Arc a: n.arcList){
       if(n.value + a.weight < a.head.value){
        a.head.value = n.value + a.weight;  // Update the weight of each node that is adjacent to the minimum-
        n.prev = a;
       }

Comment: Sorry: I see now that the loop structure is different from what I 'thought' (tired + the indentation is not consistent), so disregard my comments, mostly. Maybe this whole answer should be deleted, I'll try to think a little more, since I started commenting; so we'll see...

Comment: Hm, now I believe I my comments are somewhat useful again, so undelete. Hope you'll sort it out; I am clearly too tired & useless today.

Comment: Y i understand the problem, im jut unable to solve it cuz i cant code for shit